# Problem setting number formatting in Table output after using estadd/esttab

Tags: tables, statistics

I'm trying to create a Table using the **esttab** command and since I want to add a scalar I do it using the **estadd** command.

The scalar is generated successfully but once I create the Table, some of the values of the scalar appear with many decimal places. This is even though I set the appropriate formatting for the statistics in the **esttab** command as seen below.

```
eststo: reg y x
su y 
local contmean = r(mean)
local rcont = round(`contmean', 0.001)
estadd local cont = `rcont'
esttab using "table.tex", b(%9.3f) se(%9.3f) ///
stats(cont N r2, label( "Control Mean" "N" "R2") fmt(%9.3f 0 %9.3f)) style(tex) 
eststo clear
```

I've tried to work around it by rounding up the number itself using the round() function but even this didn't work. The strange thing is that:

1. The other stats (N r2) appear with the correct formatting (0 %9.3f)
2. This imprecision in the presentation of the scalar occurs only with some variables, not with others (see Figure)

[image]

I was told in Statalist this was a precision issue but I don't see how I can work around it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing to the package author I found that the problem was solved if instead of adding the coefficients as locals (strings) I added them as scalars (numbers).

The above code should look like:

```
eststo: reg y x
su y 
estadd scalar cont = r(mean)

esttab using "table.tex", b(%9.3f) se(%9.3f) ///
stats(cont N r2, label( "Control Mean" "N" "R2") fmt(%9.3f 0 %9.3f)) style(tex)
```

And then the Tables will display the coefficients with the intended precision :)

s/o to Benn Jann!